# Pairwise distance two matrix R

Tags: r, row, pairwise

I want to run distance bewteen matrix in R. In this example I use manhattan distance but I would like to apply other formuls.  My question is , is there one way to apply function to row of a matrix by row of other matrix in R?

In this example I have only two variables but I would like to apply with more than 10 vars.

Thanks.

```
set.seed(123)
mat1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:10000,3), 
                   z=sample(1:10000,3))
mat2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,3), 
                   z=sample(1:1000,3))

dista<-matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=2)
for (j in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat2)){
    dista[i,j]<-sqrt((mat1[i,1]-mat2[j,1]) + (mat1[i,2]-mat2[j,2]))
  }
}

dista
```

Comment: not really sure on what you want and your code does not run (`test` and `datos` are not defined). Please be more clear and what your end result should look like (paste the output of `dista`) and update your code so it runs

Comment: @boski yes sorry, i updated my code. My question is releated at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428127/implementing-knn-with-different-distance-metrics-using-r but this solutions is slow. is there one way to do it faster? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`proxy`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proxy) package for these problems.
By default, `proxy::dist` considers each row of a matrix or data frame as a single "object".

```
library(proxy)

proxy::dist(mat1, mat2, method="Manhattan")
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,]  4804  4832  4656
[2,]  3708  3736  3560
[3,] 17407 17435 17259

proxy::dist(mat1, mat2, method="Euclidean")
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,]  3397.036  3417.059  3295.962
[2,]  2761.996  2787.495  2708.075
[3,] 12308.674 12328.422 12204.286
```

Type `vignette("overview", "proxy")` in the R console to see which similarities and distances it includes,
and check the documentation of `proxy::pr_DB` if you would like to add your own functions that can be used with `proxy::dist`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still wrong as the output should be of length `nrow(mat1) * nrow(mat2)` which is `9`, and that cannot fit in a 2x2 matrix (which you previously define). Also, the `i` should run through `mat1` and `j` through `mat2`; you have it the other way around. Changing `dista[i,j] <-` for a `print()`, you'd obtain:

```
dista<-matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=2)
for (i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(mat2)){
        print(sqrt((mat1[i,1]-mat2[j,1]) + (mat1[i,2]-mat2[j,2])))
    }
}
[1] 105.8159
[1] 129.5261
[1] 63.52165
[1] 103.257
[1] 127.4441
[1] 59.1608
[1] 105.8253
[1] 129.5338
[1] 63.53739
```

You can use `outer` to limit the calculations to just one vectorised function

```
y = outer(1:nrow(mat1),1:nrow(mat2),paste)
y
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "1 1" "1 2" "1 3"
[2,] "2 1" "2 2" "2 3"
[3,] "3 1" "3 2" "3 3"

sapply(as.vector(y), function(x){
  aux = as.numeric(strsplit(x," ")[[1]])
  sqrt((mat1[aux[1],1]-mat2[aux[2],1]) + (mat1[aux[1],2]-mat2[aux[2],2]))})

      1 1       2 1       3 1       1 2       2 2       3 2       1 3       2 3       3 3 
105.81588 129.52606  63.52165 103.25696 127.44411  59.16080 105.82533 129.53378  63.53739
```

Here, we first create a `y` matrix which contains all the `i` and `j` combinations, feed it to `sapply` and then split it to get `i` and `j` individually.

Comment: thanks. yes, It is wrong, is there one way to it without loop?

Comment: `sapply(1:nrow(mat1), function(i) sapply(1:nrow(mat2), function(j) sqrt(sum(mat1[i, ] - mat2[j, ]))))`